# Selenium.WebDriver 3.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 - C#, VS 2017 Community for Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, appium

I have a console application using Selenium 3.4.0 and Appium 3.0.0.2 (I do have access to the source code for editing). I am attempting to make a UI using ASP .NET Core Web API, however if I attempt to install the NuGet Selenium and Appium WebDriver packages, I get the following error:
    For Selenium:

```
Package Selenium.WebDriver 3.4.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) / win-x86. Package Selenium.WebDriver 3.4.0 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
```

For Appium

```
Package Appium.WebDriver 3.0.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Appium.WebDriver 3.0.0.2 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Selenium.WebDriver 3.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1   (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) / win-x86. Package Selenium.WebDriver 3.0.1 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
Checking compatibility for Selenium.Support 3.0.1 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Package Selenium.Support 3.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) / win-x86. Package Selenium.Support 3.0.1 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
Checking compatibility for Castle.Core 3.3.3 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Package Castle.Core 3.3.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) / win-x86. Package Castle.Core 3.3.3 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - sl4 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0)
  - sl5 (Silverlight,Version=v5.0)
```

Is there a way around this error to add the packages? If not, is there a way in which I can have the console application do its own thing while the Web API sends and receives information from it?

I am relatively new to this environment, so please don't assume I know much. From my Googling, I haven't seen many posts similar to this problem, so generality in answering would also be helpful.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Core is not supported by Selenium at this time, but a [Pull Request exists](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/2269) to remedy that. You could try the [CoreCompat.Selenium.WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.Selenium.WebDriver/3.4.0-beta001) NuGet package in the mean time. The [Appium .Net driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver) uses the official Selenium C# client, so its likely not going to change until the Selenium .Net core PR is accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and for the links! I added the package (no errors) and can successfully compile the parts of the code only pertaining to web automation (the driver will unfortunately not load at the moment but that's another issue).